# How to implement something like Facebook Service

Tags: android, facebook, background-process

I am new to android app development and I have learnt that from Android Oreo we are supported to use Job Scheduler, because Android OS doesn't allow background services to run for long durations (unless it is a foreground service).

But I recently noticed Facebook Service running for 28+ hours without having a foreground notification.

[image: Background Facebook Service]

**Question: How does one implement this?**

NOTE: On my samsung phone Facebook is a system application and cannot be uninstalled.